# Import rows from another spreadsheet (containing multiple tabs) when column contains value

Tags: import, google-sheets, match

### What I have

This [google spreadsheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DoNAvP4rgoIpVgVZmbbDW9IKEd_1WcAWJDPurS2xiTE/edit?usp=sharing) containing multiple tabs. All the tabs have the same column layout.

### What i need to do

Copy in a new spreadsheet all the rows from the spreadsheet when the column "3" contains a specific number.

### What i've done

I've managed something like this:

```
={Query(importRange("URL"; "modulo!A2:O10"); "select * where (Col3=1)");Query(importRange("URL"; "modulo1!A2:O10"); "select * where (Col3=1)");Query(importRange("URL"; "modulo2!A2:O10"); "select * where (Col3=1)");Query(importRange("URL"; "modulo3!A2:O10"); "select * where (Col3=1)")}
```

It seems to work, but if the Column "3" doesn't contain the specific number in one or more tabs, the function give me the error: In ARRAY LITERAL, missing values in a literal expression of matrix to one or more lines.

How can i avoid this behavior? Is there a better code for solve my task?

Comment: you may use a iferror above your query and change the result for an empty row: `iferror(Query(IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheetId","A2:B10"),"select * where (Col2=1)"),{"",""});`

Comment: doesn't seems to work, it return me an error in the analysis of the formula

Comment: you did change the Nbr of `""` accordingly to the Nbr of column you have?

Comment: like this? `{"1","15"});`

Comment: well no, if you have 3 columns : `{"","",""}`if you have 4 : `{"","","",""}` and so on. The error you are facing is due that you are aggregating "null" result with column result. As they don't have the same size (number of column) it fail. You can only aggregate table of the same length

Comment: Done as you say, but still give me an error. I have 15 column and the function looks like this: 

`code =iferror(Query(importRange("url"; "modulo!A2:O10"), "select * where (Col3=1)"), {"","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""})`

Comment: you should decompose your formula to see on what level the trouble is. For what I see the importRange formula is not provided with good argument it shouldn't be "url" but "spreadsheet_id". Anyway if it's still not working you'll need to share a document to check what's wrong

Comment: i just add the link to the spreadsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a working demo good sir:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nEEMEXRuCmRFHghyYdZxXUR0q1CPgpecNQUt_AhCQSI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: as example it works good. I'm trying it on muìy working sheets, but i alway get an error. This is the [DAILY SHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19xEpZ_UHqlX1YGc2VLTMMPcdU8M7C_jHgKb8VWNBHNY/edit#gid=1381315280) from where i want to extract data (only the first tab is populated for now), and [THIS SHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i5j1kxuwiLg5jpVaLQa03u6FAiajlgzdu_27RAleXKw/edit#gid=0) is the one in which i want to have the selected data

Comment: your first reference in cell "B5" has less column than the other ones. You can only add range with the same amount of columns (rows numbers can vary)